# Stackoverflow Exception caused by object relationalship (EF4)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stack-overflow

i found many posts explain how to resolve the same issue that i have, but not in my case  :

so i have 4 classes :

Context Classes : `Client`, `Rerservation`.
Other classes : `ClientDto`, `ReservationDto`.

i added this line to make relationship between classes

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Reservation, ReservationDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ClientDto, Client>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ReservationDto, Reservation>();
```

Client DTO Classes:

```
public class ClientDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ReservationDto> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

Reservation DTO classe :

```
public class ReservationDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ClientDto Client{ get; set; }
}
```

So when i would to get list of Client from database :

```
public IEnumerable<ClientDto> GetClients(Expression<Func<ClientDto, bool>> expression, int count)
{
    return _context.Clients.Project().To<ClientDto>().Where(expression.Expand());
}
```

i got this error message :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

**if i remove reservation relationsShip from ClientDto classe, it's work fine !!**

RelationShip :

[image]

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146736/entity-framework-navigation-property for more more information.

Comment: Thank's , but this cannot resolve my issue

Comment: You have a cyclic relationship which results in an infinite object graph which you obviously can't fully map to DTOs. Do you need both `Reservations` and `Client` on your DTOs, removing one or the other would solve this issue.

Comment: i checked my code o, have juste one relation between client and reservation please see my post again i changed it !

Comment: if i remove for example Client object from reservation, i will not extract client from reservation object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ben suggested, you have a circular reference: `ClientDto` contains a collection of `ReservationDto`'s, each of them, in turn, contains back reference to its `ClientDto` owner.

You may check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505128/circular-reference-causing-stack-overflow-with-automapper) for some ideas on how to deal with circular references with Automapper.